# How to select the file with the maximum number of the specified file

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to keep only the file with the largest version of the specified zip file in the folder using powershell. I wrote a shell script but it returns all the files. How can I modify the script to select only the file with the largest version?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.zip"

$max = $files |Measure-Object -Maximum| ForEach-Object {[int]($_.Split("_")[-1].Split(".")[0])}
$largestFiles = $files | Where-Object {[int]($_.Split("_")[-1].Split(".")[0]) -eq $max}
Write-Output $largestFiles
```

Expectation:

```
A1_Fantasic_World_20.zip
A1_Fantasic_World_21.zip
B1_Mythical_Realms_11.zip
B1_Mythical_Realms_12.zip
C1_Eternal_Frame_Corporation_2.zip
C1_Eternal_Frame_Corporation_3.zip
↓
A1_Fantasic_World_21.zip
B1_Mythical_Realms_12.zip
C1_Eternal_Frame_Corporation_3.zip
```

A1_Fantasic_World's biggest number is 21.B1_Mythical_Realms's is 12.C1_Eternal_Frame_Corporation's is 3. So I want to choose the biggest version of zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you add the calculated properties to your file system objects you use for filtering. Then with a combination of `Group-Object`, `Sort-Object` and `Select.Object` you can filter the desired files.

```
$FileList =
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip |
Select-Object -Property *,
@{
    Name       = 'Title'
    Expression = {($_.BaseName -split '_')[0..$(($_.BaseName -split '_').count - 2)] -join '_' }
},
@{
    Name       = 'Counter'
    Expression = {[INT]($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1]}
}

$LastOnesList =
$FileList |
Group-Object -Property Title |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property Counter | Select-Object -Last 1
}
$LastOnesList |
Select-Object -Property Name
```

Comment: I have changed several words and sentences. Please check them.

Comment: The $FileList content is what I need. This problem is solved.

Comment: Sorry, it's all files as you know them, I'll check $LastOnesList too.

Comment: I've checked and there's no problem. Thank you very much.